# AngularJS $http dosen't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie with AngularJS i want to retrive all products in an html page but it shows nothing even if '/allProd' works perfectly without angular

**app.js**

```
var app=angular.module('crm',[]);
app.controller('CRMController', function($scope,$http){
  $scope.products=[];
  $http.get('/allProd')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.products=data;
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html data-ng-app="crm" >
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Catalog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="CRMController">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> REF </th><th> DES </th><th> PRICE </th>
      </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody > 
      <tr data-ng-repeat="p in products.content">
        <td>{{p.reference}}</td> 
        <td>{{p.designation}}</td>
        <td>{{p.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[What i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlM0t.png)

PS: I'm using angular 1.5.6 and spring-boot 1.5.2.RELEASE

Comment: Have you verified if your `data` variable is null?

Comment: a quick look at your html <tr data-ng-repeat="p in products.content"> and the what you got data. it should be <tr data-ng-repeat="p in products">

Comment: it works thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) the actual response body is in the `data` property of the response.

```
$http.get('/allProd')
.then(function(response){
    $scope.products = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do

```
$scope.products = response.data
```

Also in your ng-repeat you have to mention an array, but it seems your initialization and assignment are not in sync for $scope.products in the controller.

If `response.data.products` is not an array, there is no point declaring `$scope.products` as an array

Answer (score 0):

It is because data received on success has another property called data inside, which actually holds the required Products data.

try changing the code to

```
var app=angular.module('crm',[]);
app.controller('CRMController', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.products=[];
        $http.get('/allProd')
         .then(function(data){
         $scope.products=data.data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing in your .js file:
$scope.products=data.data;

Then, change your .html file from **"p in products.content"**
to the following:
**"p in products"**

You don't need .content.  because .content is no part of data structure.

Comment: Ah...Charlie Ng beats me on this.